# Finding area of the shaded part

Tags: geometry, area

The big square given below is made up of four equal small squares. The area of the unshaded part is $ 108 $ cm$^2$. What is the area of the shaded part?

What I tried : I tried to see if I can solve this with the theory of equilateral and Isosceles triangles (combination of the shaded and unshaded).

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: What have you tried? There are lots of triangles here whose area you can find pretty easily.

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote.

Comment: Do you remember the formula for the area of a $\triangle$?

Comment: Suggestion: Use Pick’s Theorem to compute the area of the shaded region. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick's_theorem

Comment: Hint: fold the “arms” of the V down along the horizontal line.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is $\frac13 \times 108 = 36$ cm<sup>2</sup>.

The key is if you slide the vertex $X$ of a triangle $XYZ$ along any line 
parallel to $YZ$, the area of the triangle remains unchanged. From the picture
below, one can see that the area covered by the quadrilateral (in red) is one third of the uncovered area (in light orange).

[image: quadrilateral sliding inside a square]

Comment: How did u manage with the animation??!

Comment: @tatan I use [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/) to generate the animation. In GeoGebra, you first add a slider represent the time $t$, figure out where the vertices should go at time $t$ and then export the graphics to an animated gif. It is not that great but it does do the job.

Comment: @achillehui, I think you have a typo here, it should be $\frac13 \times 108 = 36$

Comment: @Seyed thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 0):

Each shaded triangle is $\frac14$ of the sub-square it is in. The lower ones are half of half of the square when divided vertically. The upper ones use the main  diagonal to divide the square into two, and the other diagonal removes a quarter again.

This makes the area of the unshaded area three times the area of the shaded area, so the answer is $36\text{cm}^2$.

Comment: "Each shaded triangle is 1/4th of the sub-square it is in." how do you say this?

Comment: @R_D; edited my A

Answer (score 0):

Assume each side of the internal squares equal to $a$. Then you'll see the area of each white area (the top triangle, and the two right-angle triangles) is $a^2$, and hence, $3a^2$ together, or 
\begin{align}
3a^2&=108\,\mathrm{cm^2}\\
 \implies a^2&=36\,\mathrm{cm^2}
\end{align}

So, the remaining area, the shaded part, would be $4a^2-3a^2=a^2$, which equals $36\,\mathrm{cm^2}$.